# Regular expression in Dreamweaver to comment out css

Tags: html, css, regex

I am trying to convert a template from responsive to non-responsive (I know, seems crazy but...) so I was told by the template developer to comment out or remove all the @media css in the file. So I am looking for a regular expression that will go through a css file and find:

> @media { some css here }} and replace it with
>
> /* @media { same css as above }} */

I have tried variation on some examples that are similar on the webs but to no avail.

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: Please post what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

`@media.*?{\s*(?:.*?{.*?}\s*)*?}`

And then use the following string for the replacement:

`/* $0 */`

Also, for this regex to work you must use the "dot matches all" option for regular expressions. In most languages this is done with the `/s` modifier (or in something like Notepad++ there's a checkbox option that says ". matches newline").

If you are using something like Notepad++ to perform the replacement, you'll want the escaped version:

`@media.*?{\s*(?:.*?\{.*?\}\s*)*?\}`

Regex Explanation:

The `@media.*?{` part matches up to the opening brace of the media query. Then there's `\s*` to match possible white-space before the start of the inner CSS. Next, `(?:.*?{.*?}\s*)*?` will match all of the inner CSS. Finally, the end of the media query is matched with the closing brace `}`.